# How can I filter a TreeStore in ExtJS 6.2?

Tags: extjs4.2, extjs6-classic

I need to filter a Tree (search for a node by comparing a text to a node attribute).

This [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ag) is exactly what I need, but seems it is not working with ExtJS 6.2.

After a day trying to find out what is wrong in my code, I've decided to simply change the framework version in the fiddle from 4.2.1 (default) to 6.2.981 classic gray and can see the code is obsolete (removing all nodes or an arbitrary amount I can't see why).

Can someone verify that code and tell me how to port it to v6.2?

EDIT:

Almost there. This code is doing the job, but stops in deep level 2, not all the tree: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slemmon/fSJwF/2/)

```
Ext.define('TreeFilter', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.treefilter',
    collapseOnClear: true, // collapse all nodes when clearing/resetting the filter
    allowParentFolders: false, // allow nodes not designated as 'leaf' (and their child items) to  be matched by the filter

    init: function(tree) {
        var me = this;
        me.tree = tree;

        tree.filter = Ext.Function.bind(me.filter, me);
        tree.clearFilter = Ext.Function.bind(me.clearFilter, me);
    },


    filter: function(value, property, re) {
            var me = this,
                tree = me.tree,
                matches = [], // array of nodes matching the search criteria
                root = tree.getRootNode(), // root node of the tree
                property = property || 'text', // property is optional - will be set to the 'text' propert of the  treeStore record by default
                re = re || new RegExp(value, "ig"), // the regExp could be modified to allow for case-sensitive, starts  with, etc.
                visibleNodes = [], // array of nodes matching the search criteria + each parent non-leaf  node up to root
                viewNode;

            if (Ext.isEmpty(value)) { // if the search field is empty
                me.clearFilter();
                return;
            }

            tree.expandAll(); // expand all nodes for the the following iterative routines

            // iterate over all nodes in the tree in order to evalute them against the search criteria
            root.cascadeBy(function(node) {
                if (node.get(property).match(re)) { // if the node matches the search criteria and is a leaf (could be  modified to searh non-leaf nodes)
                    matches.push(node) // add the node to the matches array
                }
            });

            if (me.allowParentFolders === false) { // if me.allowParentFolders is false (default) then remove any  non-leaf nodes from the regex match
                Ext.each(matches, function(match) {
                    if (!match.isLeaf()) {
                        Ext.Array.remove(matches, match);
                    }
                });
            }

            Ext.each(matches, function(item, i, arr) { // loop through all matching leaf nodes
                root.cascadeBy(function(node) { // find each parent node containing the node from the matches array
                    if (node.contains(item) == true) {
                        visibleNodes.push(node) // if it's an ancestor of the evaluated node add it to the visibleNodes  array
                    }
                });
                if (me.allowParentFolders === true && !item.isLeaf()) { // if me.allowParentFolders is true and the item is  a non-leaf item
                    item.cascadeBy(function(node) { // iterate over its children and set them as visible
                        visibleNodes.push(node)
                    });
                }
                visibleNodes.push(item) // also add the evaluated node itself to the visibleNodes array
            });

            root.cascadeBy(function(node) { // finally loop to hide/show each node
                viewNode = Ext.fly(tree.getView().getNode(node)); // get the dom element assocaited with each node
                if (viewNode) { // the first one is undefined ? escape it with a conditional
                    viewNode.setVisibilityMode(Ext.Element.DISPLAY); // set the visibility mode of the dom node to display (vs offsets)
                    viewNode.setVisible(Ext.Array.contains(visibleNodes, node));
                }
            });
        }

        ,
    clearFilter: function() {
        var me = this,
            tree = this.tree,
            root = tree.getRootNode();

        if (me.collapseOnClear) {
            tree.collapseAll();
        } // collapse the tree nodes
        root.cascadeBy(function(node) { // final loop to hide/show each node
            viewNode = Ext.fly(tree.getView().getNode(node)); // get the dom element assocaited with each node
            if (viewNode) { // the first one is undefined ? escape it with a conditional and show  all nodes
                viewNode.show();
            }
        });
    }
});


// EXAMPLE
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "detention",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "homework",
            expanded: false,
            children: [{
                text: "book report",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "algebra",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }, {
            text: "chores",
            expanded: false,
            children: [{
                text: "do homework",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "walk dog",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "clean room",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "wash dishes",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "laundry",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }, {
            text: "buy lottery tickets",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "take over world",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Sencha",
            expanded: false,
            children: [{
                text: "Touch",
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Viewport',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Panel',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Carousel',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "ExtJS",
                expanded: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'viewport.Viewport',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'panel.Panel',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'tree.Panel',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'treefilter',
        allowParentFolders: true
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'trigger',
            triggerCls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
            onTriggerClick: function() {
                this.reset();
                this.focus();
            },
            listeners: {
                change: function(field, newVal) {
                    var tree = field.up('treepanel');

                    tree.filter(newVal);
                },
                buffer: 250
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Why `Ext.data.NodeStore` and not `Ext.data.TreeStore` ?

Answer (score -1):

Without using filter plugin i have added some useful code in change event and it works for all depth.

```js
"dockedItems": [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield', //As of Ext JS 5.0 trigger class has been deprecated.  It is recommended to use {@link Ext.form.field.Text Text Field}.
                triggerCls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
                width: 300,
                onTriggerClick: function () {
                    this.reset();
                    this.focus();
                },
                listeners: {
                    change: function (field, newVal) {
                        var reportBuilderStore = field.up('panel').getStore();
                        if (!Ext.isEmpty(field.value)) {
                            reportBuilderStore.filterBy(function (rec) {
                                var childs = !Ext.isEmpty(rec.get('children')) ? rec.get('children').map(function (x) {
                                        return x.text;
                                    }) : [];
                                var matched = false;
                                for (var val of childs) {
                                    if (val.toUpperCase().match((field.value).toUpperCase())) {
                                        matched = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!Ext.isEmpty(rec.get('text').toUpperCase().match((field.value).toUpperCase())) || rec.get('text').toUpperCase() == "ROOT" || matched)
                                    return true;
                            });
                        } else {
                            reportBuilderStore.clearFilter();
                        }
                    },
                    buffer: 250
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.